# Image outline shows as square on Safari

Tags: html, css, outline, border-radius

My HTML/CSS code makes a round image, and puts a solid outline around it, it works perfectly on Chrome and looks like this:

[image: A man's portrait clipped in a gray circle over a white background]

But on Safari the outline shows as a square:

[image: The same portrait, still clipped in a circle but with a gray rectangle outside of it]

This is my code:

```css
.iconObjBig {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="personPortraitContainer">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="iconObjBig" style="outline: 1.5rem solid rgba(154, 173, 184, 0.2); margin: 100px;">
</div>
```

I've tried setting the `border-radius` to `100`, and other things, but nothing seems to work...  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug from safari? But you can use `border` instead of `outline` the formrer works on both browsers

Comment: did you try : -webkit-border-radius: 50%;

Comment: I ended up using box-shadow instead which worked perfectly for safarit :)